# Why is the congruent number problem open?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I was reading up about the congruent number problem.

One of the theorems on the subject says how the two things are equivalent: a positive integer $n$ being a congruent number and elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3-n^2 x$ having a non trivial rational solution. Later on, the notes say that the Congruent Number Problem is still an open one.

Now my question is, doesn't the above result give a criterion to determine whether a given positive integer is a congruent number or not? Could the reason be that we don't have a way of knowing when such elliptic curves have a non trivial solution and hence no straight way of knowing if $n$ is a congruent number?
And wait, when we say, we're looking for a criterion, what exactly do we mean?

P.S.: I'm new to the theory of elliptic curves so apologies if the above question seems a bit ignorant or not per MO's standards.

Comment: It is definitely an interesting question, but I would say not a research one, so may not be the best suited for this site. That said, the congruent number problem essentially asks for a *computational proceedure* which will tell us, in finite time, whether $n$ is a congruent number. As you realize, this reduces to the problem of determining whether an elliptic curve has a rational point, but we don't have a (provably correct!) methods to verify that.

Comment: For instance if this theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnell%27s_theorem could be made unconditional, then we would have a procedure.

Comment: It's open because no one has solved it yet

Comment: @Wojowu: Ah, that makes sense then. It was not mentioned anywhere that it had to be a finite time algorithm, hence the confusion. Thanks for making it clear you and Chris!

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao To me the question reads "why doesn't the elliptic curve criterion solve the problem", which basically comes down to what the problem is in the first place (which I hope has now been clarified)

Comment: For your interest: the book GTM 97 by Koblitz explains all the story, including the dependence on the (weak) BSD conjecture.